# Setting the value in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, laravel-5, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete for a input box of cities but when i send the input it sends the name of the selected city rather than the id, how do i send the id but still show the name when using autocomplete?

so in essence i want autocomplete to be like:

< -option value="{{$city->id}}">{{city->name}}<-/option->

Here is my current code:

HTML:

```
        <div class="search-homepage-input">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-9">
            {!! Form::text('city', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' =>'55', 'placeholder' => 'Eg. England, London, Manchester', 'id' => 'sl')) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {!! Form::submit('Find Teams', array('class' => 'btn btn-homepage'))  !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
```

PHP(Laravel):

```
 public function autoComplete(Request $request){

    $query = $request->term;
    $res = City::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orderBy('name')->paginate(5);
    foreach($res as $cities ){
        $usersArray[] = $cities->name;
    }
    return response()->json($usersArray);
}
```

JS:

```
 $('#sl').autocomplete({
            source: '/autocomplete'
        })
```

Comment: What is some example data that would be found in `$usersArray` ? If it's sending back an object versus an array, you may get varied results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like the following:

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request){
  $query = $request->term;
  $res = City::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orderBy('name')->paginate(5);
  foreach($res as $cities ){
    $usersArray[] = array(
      "label" => $cities->name,
      "value" => $cities->id
    );
  }
  return response()->json($usersArray);
}
```

Review the following page: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

> **Array:** An `array` can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
>
> - An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
> - An array of objects with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

So you wabt to return JSON like:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "label": "City",
    "value": id
  }
];
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

When the user makes a selection, it uses the `select` callback. In the above example, the `label` is shown and the user selects it. This then sets the `value` attribute to the `value` of the selected item. This can be seen here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

With your Autocomplete code, this might look like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="search-homepage-input">
  {!! Form::open(['route' => 'search.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
  <div class="col-md-9">
    {!! Form::text('city-name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' =>'55', 'placeholder' => 'Eg. England, London, Manchester', 'id' => 'sl-label')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('city-id', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'sl-id', 'style' => 'display: none;') !!}
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    {!! Form::submit('Find Teams', array('class' => 'btn btn-homepage'))  !!}
  </div>
  {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#sl').autocomplete({
  source: "/autocomplete",
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $("#sl-label").val(ui.item.label);
    return false;
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#sl-label").val(ui.item.label);
    $("#sl-id").val(ui.item.value);
    return false;
  }
});
```

This way you can collect the ID you're looking to use for search.

Comment: So how would i change the autocomplete to send that?

Comment: @detinu you would not make the change in autocomplete. This would be a change to your php. Right now you're only sending 'name' data back to autocomplete.

Comment: yes - now the drop down is showing the label- name but when i click on a drop down suggestion it enters the id into the box, what i want is the name to be in the box but the value to be the id so that when i fire off my search it can bring back a search based on that id

Comment: @detinu ok, that you then need to do in the `select` callback.